# SELECT DISTINCT not returning distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MYSQL to get the distinct emails.to values, but see results below

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails`.`to`,`emails`.`from` as fromEmail, `emails`.`time` as timestamp
FROM `emails` 
WHERE ((`emails`.`from` = 'sdadr@googlemail.com') 
OR (`emails`.`to` = '887')) 
AND (`emails`.`to` != 0) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

-

```
to    fromEmail             timestamp
370   sdadr@googlemail.com  2012-08-15 16:52:15
1923  sdadr@googlemail.com  2012-08-15 10:54:48
890   sdadr@googlemail.com  2012-08-15 10:43:06
890   sdadr@googlemail.com  2012-08-15 10:43:02
```

Why does it return a repeating 890?

Comment: Because of timestamp. Truncate timestamp to date-only.

Comment: but the timestamp is found to be different for repeated `890` right?

Comment: i only want a unique `emails`.`to`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the timestamp differs. The `DISTINCT` is meant for the whole row, not just one column.

This truncates your timestamp to the date only, then 890 won't repeat. Like suggested by  Nikola Markovinović.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails`.`to`,`emails`.`from` as fromEmail, DATE(`emails`.`time`) as timestamp
FROM `emails` 
WHERE ((`emails`.`from` = 'sdadr@googlemail.com') 
OR (`emails`.`to` = '887')) 
AND (`emails`.`to` != 0) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

If you want to truncate the seconds only, which would also lead to desired result, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails`.`to`,`emails`.`from` as fromEmail, 
DATE_FORMAT(`emails`.`time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as timestamp
FROM `emails` 
WHERE ((`emails`.`from` = 'sdadr@googlemail.com') 
OR (`emails`.`to` = '887')) 
AND (`emails`.`to` != 0) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

[Manual entry for `DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for further information.

**As per your comment, if you want to have only unique emails.to** just select that column and no further with `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails`.`to`
FROM `emails` 
WHERE ((`emails`.`from` = 'sdadr@googlemail.com') 
OR (`emails`.`to` = '887')) 
AND (`emails`.`to` != 0) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: @JakeStainer You might want to take max(timestamp) or min(timestamp) instead, in case emails got exchanged on different dates. Or simply do not select timestamp at all.

Answer (score 0):

As said, truncate to date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails`.`to`,`emails`.`from` as fromEmail, DATE(`emails`.`time`) as timestamp
FROM `emails` 
WHERE ((`emails`.`from` = 'sdadr@googlemail.com') 
OR (`emails`.`to` = '887')) 
AND (`emails`.`to` != 0) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails`.`to` 
  FROM `emails`  WHERE ((`emails`.`from` = 'sdadr@googlemail.com')  OR (`emails`.`to` = '887'))  AND (`emails`.`to` != 0)  
  ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

As per your question, you are looking for distinct `to` address which you could get it from this query.